# Animating 4 div boxes only animates 2 instead of 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a grid of 4 boxes that I want to do a fade effect on using jquery when I hover around it. Currently only 2 of the boxes animate. How do I make the other 2 boxes animate as well. Please see below snippets of my jquery code and HTML.

```
  <div class="col-6">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="card-group">

                        <div id="xxx" style="background-color: #7a3f24;" class="card text-white">
                            <img  id="xx" class="dontdisplay card-img" src="assets/images/instagram_homepage.jpg" alt="Card image">
                             <div class="card-img-overlay">
                                <p style="padding-top:100px;padding-bottom:0px;" class="card-text text-center">
                                    <ion-icon size="large" name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
                                </p>
                                <h2 style="font-family: 'Miller Text Reg', Times, Georgia, serif;" class="text-center card-title">
                                    Follow for news
                                    <br> and events
                                </h2>

                            </div> 



                        </div>

                        <div id="linkedInBox" style="background-color: #e9c9a5;" class="card text-white">
                            <img  id="li" class="dontdisplay card-img" src="assets/images/instagram_homepage.jpg" alt="Card image">
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">
                                <p style="padding-top:100px;padding-bottom:0px;" class="card-text text-center">
                                    <ion-icon size="large" name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon>
                                </p>
                                <h2 style="font-family: 'Miller Text Reg', Times, Georgia, serif;" class="text-center card-title">
                                    Follow for career opportunities
                                </h2>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block"></div>



                    <div class="card-group">

                        <div id="twitterBox" style="background-color: #23374a;" class="card bg-dark text-white">
                            <img  id="tw" class="dontdisplay card-img" src="assets/images/instagram_homepage.jpg" alt="Card image">
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">
                                <p style="padding-top:100px;padding-bottom:0px;" class="card-text text-center">
                                    <ion-icon size="large" name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
                                </p>
                                <h2 style="font-family: 'Miller Text Reg', Times, Georgia, serif;" class="text-center card-title">
                                    Follow for news
                                    <br> and conversations
                                </h2>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="instagramBox" style="background-color: #267d69;" class="card bg-dark text-white">
                            <img id="in" class="dontdisplay card-img" src="assets/images/instagram_homepage.jpg" alt="Card image">
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">
                                <p style="padding-top:100px;padding-bottom:0px;" class="card-text text-center">
                                    <ion-icon size="large" name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
                                </p>
                                <h2 style="font-family: 'Miller Text Reg', Times, Georgia, serif;" class="text-center card-title">
                                    Follow the studio for updates
                                </h2>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The above code is my HTML

```
 <script>
        $('#linkedInBox').hover(
                  function () 
                  {
                      $('#li').fadeIn('slow');
                  }, function () 
                  {
                      $('#li').fadeOut('slow');
                  }
              );
      $('#twitterBox').hover(
          function () 
          {
              $('#tw').fadeIn('slow');
          }, function () 
          {
              $('#tw').fadeOut('slow');
          }
      );
      $('#xxx').hover(
                  function () 
                  {
                      $('#xx').fadeIn('slow');
                  }, function () 
                  {
                      $('#xx').fadeOut('slow');
                  }
              );
    $('#instagramBox').hover(
        function () 
        {
            $('#in').fadeIn('slow');
        }, function () 
        {
            $('#in').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    );
  </script>
```

The code above is my Jquery code. The LinkedIn and Twitter Boxes animate as expected but the others don't. I created a css class

```
<style>

                  .dontdisplay {
                        display: none;
                    }

                </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id on #faceBookBox is wrong. Should be #facebookBox.

`$('#faceBookBox').hover(` should be `$('#facebookBox').hover(`

Also, you're closing an extra `</div>` element in your HTML.

EDIT: Add the following css to start with images hidden and only show the first time on hover. Also updated fiddle

```
img{
  display:none;
}
```

Check [this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvcgeyb8/5/).

Comment: Thanks you. I tried your suggestion and I believe it should work but I'm doing something wrong cause now, the background I set to display on the div doesn't even show anymore. I just have an blank all white space. Please see my updated code

Comment: @user2721794 Your updated code works fine on my end. You can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nvcgeyb8/9/).

Comment: Thank you. The problem is likely from scripts that are in my app that seem to be interfering with how it functions.